# Using Flow to change Client Status in Client List based on Activity Type in Activity List

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, microsoft-flow

I have a list of Clients and a list of Activities.

Activities includes two lookup columns:

1. Client
2. Activity Type

Clients includes one lookup column:

1. Client Status

What I'm trying to achieve is a Flow that does the following:

- When a new activity record is created
- Do a switch case on the Activity Type of this new record
  --  Then depending on the Activity Type
- Update the client list changing the Client Status to one of a number of predetermined Client Statuses (this maps to a status in the Client Status list but I understand the mapping is manual i.e. we'll manually enter the ID that it should change to)

My trigger is fine.

Then I try a 'get item' action to get the created record, my intention being that I want to get to the Activity Type lookup ID to do the switch case and to the Client lookup ID which I'll need in the next step to update the Client record.

In the 'Update Item' action when I add the Id (unique ID of the Client record to be updated) the list of dynamic content fields doesn't include the Client lookup ID...

What am I missing here?